# PDF417 Barcode read for Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, zxing, zbar

Im looking for an open source barcode reader to read PDF417 barcodes.
I need to integrate the library with my camera app, so I need to call only to the detection method without running the open source library camera flow.
I tried to hack Zxing but PDF417 is still in beta so the recognition not works sometimes, and Zbar does not supports PDF417.
is there any solution to make Zxing work better or alternative?

Thanks.

Comment: There are no good open source PDF417 barcode readers. Just good commercial ones.